# .NET - Is there a way to change the GC behavior for the entire machine?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-xp

A co-worker said this is possible (but it looks a bit strange to me).
If there's a way to do it, where can I do this?
I'm talking about winXP OS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the GC has two modes of operation: Server and Workstation. You can change modes in either your app.config (per application) or machine.config. See http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/archive/2004/07/13/181534.aspx for more information.

```
<Configuration>
    <runtime>
        <gcServer enabled="false" />
        <gcConcurrent enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
</Configuration>
```

For [`gcServer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357.aspx):

- **false** - Does not run server garbage collection. *This is the default.*
- **true** - Runs server garbage collection.

For [`gcConcurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhwwzef8.aspx):

- **false** - Does not run garbage collection concurrently.
- **true** - Runs garbage collection concurrently. *This is the default.*

In general, however, you don't want to change the GC operation mode, especially on a machine level unless you have a ***really***, ***really*** good reason to. Generally the only things that care about this are unmanaged applications that are hosting the CLR themselves (such as SQL Server or IIS).

Comment: Don't forget gcConcurrent, though not really a mode, it is (can be) a machine wide config to the GC

Comment: Tess Fernandez has a great article that includes details on the different GC modes -> http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/04/17/how-does-the-gc-work-and-what-are-the-sizes-of-the-different-generations.aspx