# Is there a way to optimize .NET G.C. non programmatically?

Tags: .net, optimization, garbage-collection

I would like to know if it's possible to optimize the .NET Garbage Collector using some options or properties like we can do with the Java JVM?

To add to this question, if it's possible, do you know a way to improve performance when most of the objects are stored in generation 0.
The GC stats are the following :

> number of times garbage collection 0 has occurred: 2601
>
> number of times garbage collection 1 has occurred: 42
>
> number of times garbage collection 2 has occurred: 41

Comment: You're asking how to solve a problem without describing the problem itself. What performance issues are you experiencing in your application?

Comment: To add to Allon's question: What does your application do (I mean regarding GC: how does it create objects, when does it “free” them)? The .Net GC already tunes itself during runtime, maybe you can fix your problem by changing your application.

Comment: Ok, so I have not particular performance issue I just want to try to improve performance with non-programmatical tuning. That's why I don't provide code. So basically I just want to know if there is some basic commands or options to parameter GC (like -XX:... in Java) , I will deal myself with the using of those.

Comment: If most of the objects are in gen-0, what makes you think there is a problem to solve? Gen-0 is cheap to collect - sounds like it is all working properly. Without a very specific scenario, this is unanswerable. If you were getting too much gen-2, then that is a far more interesting scenario to discuss!

Comment: @Marc While gen0 GCs are certainly preferable, there's still lots of things you could specify. For one: More but shorter gen0 GCs help to keep latency low, etc. But I fear there's not much one can do with MS's GC - last time I checked one got only the most basic properties (server/client GC and concurrent yes/no or something)

Comment: @Voo very few real problems can be fixed just by tweaking the GC; If there is a GC-related problem, it more commonly needs coding changes instead. For example, as Anders notes, sometimes changing some of the data to structs (sensibly, and thinking in great detail about what that means) can help.

Comment: @Marc And one should certainly make sure to keep that in mind while programming. Still, a low latency GC will help in any case and even with the best coding, if the GC doesn't want to play nice you can easily get problematic spikes. But yes, I agree that we want defaults that work fine in 95% of all cases, because GC tuning is pretty arcane. Still it's a downside to .NET when compared to Java that I hope MS will remedy in the future.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, from now I think there is not at lot of possibilities for tuning GC in .NET. It's what I wanted to know. @MarcGravell I don't specify a specific scenario because I want to have informations for all cases people can give me, if you know a specific trick when you have problem with generation 2, I'll be gload to know how to deal with that non-programmatically. But as you said I guess it's more code improvement that you think about.

Comment: @alain you might find this useful: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks very interesting, also nice comment about comparizon with Java!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [using a .config file to experiment with using the server GC and concurrent GC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1267652/678410).

I doubt it will have a great impact on performance. If you have most objs in Gen0 that means your application is working as it should. If there are too many tiny objects, you may have been better served with a struct for some particular type, but that of course is a programmatic change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already try this, because it's the only thing I've found. And with `<gcConcurrent enabled="false" />` it improve slightly performance. So I was looking for others command like that.